# XCFrameworks dependencies conflict

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

In my project I'm using three 3rd party frameworks:

- FrameworkA that is using FrameworkC as a dependency
- FrameworkB that is using slightly modified (at public interface) FrameworkC as a dependency

Now when I'm trying to build my project XCode throws an error:

> 'XSomeClass' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'FrameworkA' found method XXXX but in 'FrameworkB' found end of class

Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: Either synch up versions, or if you are the one building FrameworkC, rename the "slightly modified" version to something else.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to FrameworkC source code, and source code of modifications.

Comment: I can't imagine how something like this even _could_ be allowed. Same classes, same package name - how xcodebuild is supposed to know when do you mean one and when the other?

Comment: Do you have access to the FrameworkA/FrameworkB source code?